# C++ implemented data structure library?

Tags: c++

I have used java for long time and see there is an implementation for large number of data structures like lists, hash table , queues, trees extra .but now I am concerned more with c++
**is there any previous implemented library for these data structures?**

Comment: -1: for the obvious complete and total lack of research effort. All you had to search for was "C++ standard library" and you would see most of what you asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ STL that others have mentioned is useful, but is fairly limited compared to Java's set of standard libraries. You might also want to look into the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/), which is very commonly used -- you could almost think of it as an extension of the STL (in fact, some of the Boost libraries have made it into the new C++ standard).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, its called the Standard Template Library, or more recently, they're just considered part of the Standard Library.

You can use:

```
std::vector<T>
std::queue<T>
std::dequeue<T>
std::set<T>
std::map<T>
std::multiset<T>
std::multimap<T>
```

and hash tables as well on most platforms, though they're a more recent addition.  They each require a header file in their own name, except multiset and multimap which are under set and map themselves.

This whole site is rampant with examples (like every question) so just pick one and browse around.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library includes `std::list`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::queue`, and `std::set`/`std::map`, which are lists, hash tables, queues, and trees respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at c++ STL. Here is some explanation 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

The STL is a collection C++ libraries that allows you to use several data structures.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ by default you have the stl library http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/
map, queue, list, deque, vector..

as for more complexed things as trees there are million of examples and libraries developed everywhere.. often when you are in a situation where you need a special tree, perhaps a red-black tree. You learn and develop one or you try to find a library that has it.